# Do anyone know how to make a dropdowntree menu in ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, drop-down-menu

I really need to know how to make the dropdownTree Menu in ipad. I need to create it in my ipad app. If anyone out there knows it, please share it with me. Thanks a lot in advance.[image]

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? (We're not here to provide code for you.)

Comment: Daniel, I need it in my ipad app. I wanted to know how it is done.

Comment: @middaparka i tried it in UIScrollView but it never gonna do fine on reclicking of the menu drop

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't provide a native component for GUI trees. Writing one on your own can take a long time. I would rather use a webview and use a javascript tree component such as [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) or [Tree Menu](http://www.treemenu.net/treemenu/3fr_checkbox.html).

You can easily interact with the webview using these methods:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script

// UIWebViewDelegate method, to communicate from within the webview with the native objective-c code
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Comment: Thank you. I got  better idea of setting up the UITableView under the buttons I create and then show the table on the clicks.